# Upgrade Rpy2 version

Tags: python, installation, upgrade, rpy2

I have previously installed `rpy2` on my PC using the appropriate wheels from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2). However, now I need to upgrade to the latest version of rpy2. I did the following:

```
pip install rpy2 --upgrade
```

But this did not work out, and gave me the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

This same error used to pop up when I was first trying to install rpy2 and ended up downloading the precompiled binary fro [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2)

In my system environment variables I have:

- R_USER: > C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\rpy2
- R_HOME: > C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2

What should I do to upgrade rpy2 to the latest version, I have `version 2.9.5` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing an updated wheel instead of using pip.

Comment: I am searching for the updated wheel but cannot seem to find it anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support of rpy2 for Windows. It was kind of possible to compile it with a good part of it working up to the 2.9.x series but this is no longer possible.

The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/584